# MySQL error when operands orders are changed in comparison operator

Tags: mysql

I came across a strange issue in MySQL where when I change the order of the operands it is throwing error. The below queries executed without selecting any database:

1. `SELECT TIME(NOW()) < '12:40:45';`
2. `SELECT '12:40:45' > TIME(NOW());`

are working fine in my local system (v8.0.25) but in my dev environment (v8.0.1-dmr) #2  is throwing error[image]

Want to know what could be the reason for this.

Comment: The collations on the two databases are different.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen first of all the collations are same. Second yes there is collation issue but why #1 works and not #2 and also why both works in my local system. Again here the query is directly executed without selecting any database.

Comment: [Release notes for v8.0.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-1.html): *This release makes several important changes in Unicode character set support. In particular, the default character set has changed from latin1 to utf8mb4.* and *This is a milestone release, for use at your own risk.* I'd be surprise if you *don't* find any bugs regarding character sets.

Answer (score 0):

The condition may have either string or datetime context. The context is defined by the former operand.

In the 1st query it is datetime. And none problem occures.

In the 2nd query it is defined as string. Literal collation is taken from connection settings, implicit convertion uses server collation, and you see the problem.

The source of this difference is you. You use short form of the literal which produces ambiguity. Use complete form

```
SELECT time '12:40:45' > CURRENT_TIME;
```

and the problem won't occur.

Comment: Yes it is the implicit conversion for which it is throwing error and the result should be universal but in my local system it is working fine. That is what I want to understand.

Comment: @Suraj "Everything that is not explicitly specified can be anything". As I see you use some client (phpmyadmin?). It can detect that the literal value matches the datetime pattern and hence add specificator, for example... enable General Log temporarily and get the query which is really sent to MySQL on both systems (and take into account the commands sent previously, during connecting, and also compare session SQL Mode settings).